# Firebase Cloud Storage Upload File Path Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a node.js app with Firebase Functions and using this to upload an image that is getting downloaded from another network call and stored locally.

I'm getting the following error when trying to upload an image file to storage.

It's coming from the Firebase storage node modules with this function:

```
function _getChild$1(ref, childPath) {
    const newPath = child(ref._location.path, childPath);
    const location = new Location(ref._location.bucket, newPath);
    return new Reference(ref.storage, location);
}
```

I believe the ref is referring to `storage` in my upload function `const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images');`

**ERROR:**

```
const newPath = child(ref._location.path, childPath);  
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
```

**CODE:**

```
const { ref, uploadBytes } = require('firebase/storage');
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getStorage } = require('firebase-admin/storage');

firebaseConfig = {...}
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

const uploadImagesToFirebase = async () => {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images');

    try {
        const upload = await uploadBytes(
            storageRef,
            '/Users/donovancotter/Desktop/Projects/image-uploaded/functions/public/37f8eb5d-8b42-45ed-ba3b-c7d35a299a62-0-1111264718.png'
        );
        return upload;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 0):

As you are using node import syntax, import the `ref` and `uploadBytes` functions with the import statement from the Firebase Storage client library.

You can check the below sample code for reference.Also check this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file)

```
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
const storage = getStorage();
const uploadImagesToFirebase = async () => {
    const storageRef = ref(storage, 'images/profile')
    try {
        const upload = await uploadBytes(
            storageRef,
           file //This will be your user selected file from file explorer
        );
        return upload;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue on the same spot. Aliasing of ref import 
`import { ref as storageRef } from 'firebase/storage'`
does not work as well.

 ` Unhandled Runtime Error
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
    Source
    _getChild$1
    node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.esm2017.js (3107:0)
    refFromPath
    node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.esm2017.js (3158:0)
    ref$1
    node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.esm2017.js (3175:0)
    ref
    node_modules\@firebase\storage\dist\index.esm2017.js (3544:0)
    ...`

Comment: I'm having same error, did you find a solution or work-around?